# Como chamar em PHP serviços com multiplos Binding

Tags: php, web-service, binding

Preciso conectar o PHP a um webservice .net que possui multiplos binding e ambos com métodos de mesmo nome. o `SoapClient` está sempre chamando o primeiro deles mesmo quando a `Action` e o location foram definidos explicitamente.

```
 $options = array(
           'login' => $login,
            'password' => $password,
            'trace' => true,
            'Action'=> $server.'/'.$service.'/'.$operation,
            "location" => $server.'/'.$binding
);
$client = new SoapClient($server.'?wsdl', $options);

$response = $client->operation($inputObject);
```

Comment: Oi Andrea, `__setLocation` deve / deveria funcionar (veja [esse post do SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7261461/664577)). Se você precisa extrair a porta do serviço do payload [esse artigo](https://akrabat.com/selecting-port-for-phps-soapclient/) pode ser útil

Comment: Anthony, obrigada pela atenção. No meu caso são 2 portas que apontam para o mesmo location. O que diferencia as chamadas é o caminho da soapAction de cada operação, e mesmo quando coloco explicitamente o caminho da Action, o RequestHeaders exibe o endereço da primeira Action. Ex: